# eVGA z68 FTW Motherboard - 5 beeps on boot

Tags: boot, cpu, motherboard

yesterday when I shut down my computer it was beeping 5 times and didn't shut down correctly, so I had to use the power button to kill it.
This morning when I wanted to start my PC again, it beeps 5 times and then won't boot and the screen stays black.

I'm using a eVGA Z68 FTW Motherboard with an Intel i7 2600k Processor.

I've read that 5 beeps can mean that the processor or the MB is damaged. I've already removed the RAM and put it back in, took the CPU out and put it back in after cleaning it and applying new cooler paste, but it still does not work.

Does anyone know a solution, or at least a way how I can find out which part (MB / CPU) is damaged so I can get a new one?

EDIT: Error-Code: A8

**Update**: Very strange things are happening right now. I reset the CMOS by taking the battery out for 10 minutes, but it still did not work. So I reset it using the CMOS-Reset button on the MB - also does not work. Although, the error-codes have changed. This is what is going on:

1. I reset the CMOS using the CMOS-Reset button on the Mainboard.
2. I start my Computer while I watch the error codes. It gets stuck at **d6** ("No Console Output Devices are found"), beeps 5 times and then automatically tries to boot again. It gets stuck at **d6** again, beeps 5 times and stays there. Nothing happens anymore.
3. I turn my Computer off and start again.
4. It gets stuck at **d6** again, beeps 5 times, but then jumps to **A8** ("Setup Verifying Password") and stays there.

From now on, on every boot the error is **A8**. But when I reset the CMOS again, the procedure starts at point 1 again.

Comment: What is the two digit post code? http://imgur.com/EScXTgD from [motherboard user manual](https://www.evga.com/support/manuals/files/160-SB-E689.pdf)

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that I can see a code there. It's A8

Comment: "A8 - Setup Verifying Password" [Sandy Bridge and Ivy Bridge Post Codes List for P67, Z68, Z77, Z87, Z97, X79, SR-X](http://www.evga.com/support/faq/afmmain.aspx?faqid=59363). I've no idea what it means :/

Comment: Thank you! I have a BIOS Password set, does that mean that it can not be verified? I don't even get the point where I have to type it in.

Comment: You could try to [reset bios z68 ftw](http://forums.evga.com/reset-bios-z68-ftw-m1844448.aspx)